# How to create a preview for component in delphi?

Tags: delphi, components, visualization

On some programs there is an interesting possibility:
in case the work area is very large, there is the overall picture, which provided by the plan of all component.
Which component allows you to add this capability to my program?
I would like to implement this, at least for StringGrid and TChart.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPQcG.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

To do this in a generic way, you have to do [off-screen painting](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2012/01/improved-painting.html).

That is a lot of work, especially getting the details right.

[JED Software](http://www.jed-software.com) once write something similar to show previews of forms in the IDE called [Visual Forms](http://www.jed-software.com/vf.htm) and it took them a long time.

Comment: Thank you!
I hope, We can find a component, which helps us to add a preview in  program in easy way.

Comment: You might want to contact JED Software. They might be able to help you out to get started. Probably cheaper than doing all the work yourself.